# Python parse csv file - replace commas with colons

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I suspect this is a common problem, but I counldn't seem to locate the answer. I am trying to remove all commas from a csv file and replace them with colons. I would normally use sed or vi for this, but I need to use a purely python implementation. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
import csv

with open("temp.csv", mode="rU") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, dialect="excel")    
    with open("temp2.txt", mode="w") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for rows in reader:
            for parsed_item in rows:
                parsed_item = rows.replace(',', ':') # I can't do this with a list!
                writer.writerow(parsed_item)
```

Can anyone help me out with how to do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I see from the answers that their are two interpretations of your question.  Some think you want to change the delimeter to a colon.  Others think you want replace any commas in each item.  Which is it?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity of my question. I intended to ask how to change the delimiter from a comma to a colon. I  didn't know it was as simple as specifying the delimiter as a colon. For some reason I didn't think that would work. Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is easier than you think.  You just need to set the delimiter for `csv.writer`:

```
import csv

row = #your data

with open("temp.csv", mode="rU") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, dialect="excel")    
    with open("temp2.txt", mode="w") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=':')
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

You're line trying to replace `,` with `:` wasn't going to do anything because the row had already been processed by `csv.reader`.

Comment: ...rows is not defined here. I'm unsure what it's supposed to refer to.

Comment: Replace `writer.writerows(rows)` for `writer.writerows(list(reader))`, or even better `writer.writerows(reader)`

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking to read a csv with comma delimiter and write it in **another file** with semicolon delimiters. I think a more straightforward way would be:

```py
reader = csv.reader(open("input.csv", "r"), delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'), delimiter=';')
writer.writerows(reader)
```

I find this example much easier to understand than with the `with open(...)`.
Also if you work with file using comma and semicolon as delimiters. You can use the [Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) of the csv file to detect which delimiter is used before reading the file (example in the link).

Also if you want to rewrite in the same file, check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49414740/7747942).

Comment: The downside here is that you don't close the file objects you've opened, eg. `f.close()`. Using `with open(...)` this gets done automatically. Better to name them and close them after you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Pros and cons, in this particular case the `with open(...)` just to automatically close is not that much of a help in my opinion.

Comment: Indeed [@Bhanunday Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8957899/bhanuday-sharma), the `U` is deprecated so I removed it. Apparently `newline=None` is the [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791545/what-is-the-non-deprecated-version-of-open-u-mode) and does the same thing as the U was suppose to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I will build my answer on @Sylhare's answer. In python3, the 'U' mode is deprecated. So, the following solution worked for me:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("input.csv", newline=None), delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'), delimiter=':')
writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: This could have been a comment, I updated it ;)

Comment: @Sylhare Yes. You are right. But at that time I didn't have the privilege to comment. Anyway, thanks for both the original and updated answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing csv files from JSON raw data and noticed that the `DictWriter` module also supports different delimiters. Example:

```
with open('file_1.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig", newline = '') as myfile:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, fieldnames = table_fields, delimiter=';')
    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerows(# my data #)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the CSV is comma delimited, and you want to replace commas in each entry, I believe the issue is replacing the wrong item:

```
for rows in reader:
    for parsed_item in rows:
        parsed_item = parsed_item.replace(',', ':') # Change rows to parsed_item
        writer.writerow(parsed_item)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're just replacing commas with colons, you don't need to use a csv parser at all.

```
with open("file.csv", 'r') as f:
    with open("temp.csv", 'w') as t:
        for lines in f:
            new_line = line.replace(",",":")
            t.write(new_line)
```

The only caveat is that you can't have commas elsewhere in the csv file.

Comment: There's a typo on the 4th line; line.replace should be lines.replace

Comment: CSV has some different flavours, but in  most of them there are special ways to escape commas inside data, which need to be taken into account, so a simple replace won't do.