# How to set appengine bulkupload csv delimeter?

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkinsert, appcfg

i am a java programmer trying to use python 
'appcfg.py upload_data' on appengine

Is it possible to set a csv delimeter on config.yml (as in ->   1#2#2#3 where # is the delimeter)

I see that there is a 'connector_options:' on config.yml

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `appcfg.py upload_data` operation is not present in the current [`appcfg.py` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments).

There used to be a related section in the [Backing Up and Restoring](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring) guide, but it's now gone. From a snapshot of it captured in the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210190351/https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata):

> **`csv` connector**
>
> `encoding`
>
> Any [Python standard encoding format](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210190351/http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), such as `utf-8` (the
>   default) or `windows-1252`.
>
> `column_list`
>
> Use a sequence of names specified here for columns on import and
>   export. If not specified, use first row of data to calculate
>   external_name of each column, then read or write data starting with
>   second row.
>
> `skip_import_header_row`
>
> If true, header line will be ignored on import.
>
> `print_export_header_row`
>
> If true, header line will be printed on export.
>
> `import_options`
>
> Additional keyword arguments for the [Python CSV module](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210190351/http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) on import.
>   Use `dialect: excel-tab` for a TSV file.
>
> `export_options`
>
> Additional keyword arguments for the [Python CSV module](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210190351/http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) on export.

Note that the links in the quote are also snapshots, you might need to check the actual links valid today. The code might be incompatible.

IMHO it would be simpler to just re-write the CSVs to replace the delimiters... See [Python parse csv file - replace commas with colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630170/python-parse-csv-file-replace-commas-with-colons)