# how to convert all dot decimal marker in csv files to comma using python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have multiple csv files.

[image]

in these files, "dot" used as a decimal marker.

[image]

I would like to change all dots to commas and then combine all csv files into one csv file. How can I do this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630170/python-parse-csv-file-replace-commas-with-colons & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256104/python-csv-change-separator

Comment: @Qiu That question changes the delimitter while op here asks to change decimal marker

Answer (score 0):

You could parse csv row per row and then use `replace()` function on values where you want to replace `.`

Then, after this transformation, you write this row on a new **CSV** file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dazounet mentioned you can read file by file and line by line and replace "manually"

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = "pathToFolder/"
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

with open(mypath + "target.csv", 'a') as outfile:
    for file in files:
        with open(mypath+file, "r") as infile:
             next(infile)
             for line in infile:
                    line = line.replace("." , ",")
                    outfile.write(line)
```

The code is not tested

Comment: thanks! this is the error that i got: files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
NameError: name 'listdir' is not defined

Comment: it destroyed the structure of the csv files. it added all the headers

Comment: just skip the first line with next(infile) to ignore the headers. i add it to the answer

Comment: now it removes all headers and add more columns! is it possible to keep the first file with its header and append other fils without headers?

Comment: yes you could do that if you want. you might consider using pandas as Daren Thomas suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` makes writing out the numbers with commas trivial:

- read in the csv file (`df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')`)
- write out the csv file (`df.to_csv('path/to/file.csv', decimal=',')`)

Note, this will add quotes to all your numbers, since the separator normally used is `,`. You can change that with the `sep=';'` argument for instance.

I'll leave finding all the files to join as an exercise for the reader (see other answers here).

As for combining all the files into one file:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in files_to_convert])
```