# What is the non deprecated version of open "U" mode

Tags: python, deprecated

I am trying to read a textfile in python using:

```
with open("Keys.txt","rU") as csvfile:
```

however this produces a depreciation warning.

```
DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
```

What is the non deprecated version for this mode of access for a text/csv file.

Comment: In Python >= 3, use newline instead, the default is newline=None which is like newline='' except it also translates the newlines to \n. I'm unsure which of these is equivalent to mode='U'

Referenced here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726953/open-the-file-in-universal-newline-mode-using-the-csv-django-module

Comment: @KyleJ: `U` behavior is part of the default behavior. You just remove it. As you say, `csv` needs `newline=''`, but that has nothing to do with `U` (which can just be removed).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's the default behaviour now, so you can simply omit it:

```
with open("Keys.txt", "r") as csvfile:
```

From the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> There is an additional mode character permitted, `'U'`, which no longer has any effect, and is considered deprecated. It previously enabled [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) in text mode, which became the default behaviour in Python 3.0. Refer to the documentation of the [newline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter) parameter for further details.

By the way, it's being removed in Python 3.11.

See also: [Why is universal newlines mode deprecated in Python? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/298677/352138)